# zsh: command not found: flutter,after adding parmanent path

Tags: macos, flutter

[image]

Can not find flutter command after adding Path permanently on mac..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make .zshrc file
make sure its plain text format
paste the Path `export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"` and save
run flutter --version

if says 'Bad CPU type in executable'
run softwareupdate --install-rosetta

it should solve the problem once and for all